# How to identify reason of OverQuotaError when sending emails?

Tags: google-app-engine, email, cron, task-queue

I send emails with cron job and task queue usage. The job is executed every 15 minutes and the queue used has the following setup:

```
- name: send-emails
  rate: 1/m
  max_concurrent_requests: 1
  retry_parameters:
    task_retry_limit: 0
```

But quite often `apiproxy_errors.OverQuotaError` exception happens. I am checking Quota Details and see that I am still within the daily quota (Recipients Emailed, Attachment Data Sent etc.), and I believe I couldn't be over [maximum per minute limit](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas?hl=en#Mail), since the the rate I use is just 1 task per minute (i.e. send no more than 1 mail per minute).

Where am I wrong and what should I check?

Comment: The queue can contain up to 100 messages. But one task is just for 1 e-mail sending. However when checking the log, I see `2014-06-02 18:43:46.514`, `2014-06-02 18:44:14.952`, `014-06-02 18:44:16.858`, which is more often, then 1 task per minute (what I've expected with `rate: 1/m`).

Comment: @GAEfan, looks like I should define `bucket_size` equal to `1` for proper `rate` usage, right?

Comment: Why are you setting such a low rate and bucket size?  Are you only sending one email every 15 minutes?  Also, did you set the taskqueue name using `.add(queue_name="send-emails")`

Comment: The bucket size limits how fast the queue is processed when many tasks are in the queue and the rate is high. This allows you to have a high rate so processing starts shortly after a task is enqueued, but still limit resource usage when many tasks are enqueued in a short period of time.

If no <bucket-size> is specified for a queue, the default value is 5.

Comment: Yes, if you only want to send one email per minute, you need to change the bucket size.  The `rate` is not the rate that emails are sent; It is the rate that the bucket is replenished.  So, the way you have it, you are sending a bucket of 5 (default `bucket-size`) emails every 1 minute

Comment: @GAEfan, answering your question about low rate and low bucket size - there are GAE limits on size and number of attachments sent per minute. I don't want to count it each time, so I am OK to send just 1 message per 1 minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many emails are you sending? You have not set a `bucket-size`, so it defaults to 5.  Your `rate` sets how often the bucket is replenished.  So, with your current configuration, you can send 5 emails every minute.  That means if you are sending more than 75 emails to the queue every 15 minutes, the queue will fill up, and eventually go over quota.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this myself, but when you catch the apiproxy_errors.OverQuotaError exception, does the message contain any detail as to why it is over quota/which quota has been exceeded?

```
try:
    send_mail_here
except apiproxy_errors.OverQuotaError, message:
    logging.error(message)
```

Comment: This is exactly how I catch the exception. The message says `The API call mail.Send() required more quota than is available`, i.e. no details.

Comment: OK, so the exception could be more helpful.